# Postgres: Query to compare Data with previous Data

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a main table where all my results will be written to.
Each object that will be checked is identified by the item_id:

```
Checkdate     item_id    Price Cat A    Price Cat B
2017-04-25    1          29.99          84.99
2017-04-24    1          39.99          89.99
2017-04-23    1          39.99          91.99
2017-04-25    2          42.99          88.99
2017-04-23    2          41.99          81.99
2017-04-22    2          50.99          81.99
2017-04-21    2          42.99          81.99
```

In the postgres query i select all results with the current_date = checkdate to provide the newest data:

```
Item    Price Cat A      Price Cat B
1       29.99            84.99
2       42.99            88.99
```

So far its not a problem for me. But now i want to compare these results with the previous results. Something like that:

```
Item    Price Cat A    Price Cat A Before   Price Cat B    Price Cat B Before
1       29.99          39.99                84.99          89.99
2       42.99          41.99                88.99          81.99
```

But I have no idea how to do that. These items doesn't exist on every day (item 2 doesn't exist on 2017-04-24 for example).

Can someone help me?

Comment: The condition `current_date = checkdate`  seems to imply that you check all your (current) items every day. Is that so? Smells funny...

Comment: What is funny on that? The application catches the newest data one time a day and stores that in a database. The query above will be called by webservices to get the newest data (with a caching functionality). current_date is needed here, because sometimes (as mentioned) items does not exist (but will maybe exists tomorrow again).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    item_id,
    min(price_cat_a) filter (where rn = 1) as a,
    min(price_cat_a) filter (where rn = 2) as a_before,
    min(price_cat_b) filter (where rn = 1) as b,
    min(price_cat_b) filter (where rn = 2) as b_before
from (
    select
        item_id, price_cat_a, price_cat_b,
        row_number() over (partition by item_id order by checkdate desc) as rn
    from t
    where checkdate <= current_date
) s
where rn <= 2
group by item_id
;
 item_id |   a   | a_before |   b   | b_before 
---------+-------+----------+-------+----------
       1 | 29.99 |    39.99 | 84.99 |    89.99
       2 | 42.99 |    41.99 | 88.99 |    81.99
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT today.item_id,
       today."Price Cat A",
       before."Price Cat A" AS "Price Cat A Before",
       today."Price Cat B",
       before."Price Cat B" AS "Price Cat B Before"
FROM main today
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT "Price Cat A",
             "Price Cat B"
      FROM main
      WHERE item_id = today.item_id
        AND "Checkdate" < today."Checkdate"
      ORDER BY "Checkdate" DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) before
WHERE today."Checkdate" = current_date
ORDER BY today.item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

*These items doesn't exist on every day* -- because of this, your original query has an error too (i.e. it won't contain all of your items).

If you are looking for the last (and the second last) `checkdate`, there is no need to use `current_date` (unless, there might be future data in your table; in that case just append `where checkdate <= current_date` to filter them out).

Finding the last row (within its group, i.e. in your case, it's `item_id`) is a typical [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, and the second last is easy with the [`lag()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
select   distinct on (item_id)
         item_id,
         price_cat_a,
         price_cat_a_before,
         price_cat_b,
         price_cat_b_before
from     (select *,
                 lag(price_cat_a) over w price_cat_a_before,
                 lag(price_cat_b) over w price_cat_b_before
          from   t
          window w as (partition by item_id order by checkdate)) t
order by item_id, checkdate desc
```

http://rextester.com/AGZ99646

Comment: Puuh, that is really complicated for me. Can you explain what the keywords "window", "partition by" mean? And furthermore the first line (distinct on (item_id))?

Comment: @user2622344 those are parts of a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) call. Read more about them in the linked resources.